# Algorithm for shortest path to cover all the routes

Tags: algorithm, graph

This is a variation of a question I came across in one of the mock-interview videos.

Assume there's a bunch of routes `ex: [rome->dallas, dallas->rome, london->paris, paris->frankfurt, london->dallas, frankfurt->rome]` etc.  Now I want to add a new location to this route ex: delhi. The question is to to find the minimum no. of connections i need to build such that I can cover all the above places from Delhi ?

My solution is:

1. Build a graph and get the list of strongly connected components in that graph.
2. Add an edge from this new location to at-least one node of every component in the list of SCC's.  Since every node is connected to every other in a SCC, adding an edge to any one of the nodes should work.

Does this solution make sense ? I'm unable to come up with a way to prove that this can work in every situation.  Is there any drawbacks of this solution ? Please share your inputs/comments.

Comment: Have you heard about this [travel-salesman-problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Is this what you mean.

Comment: @winarcooo I dont think this is the TSP problem

Comment: by adding one edge to each SCC you may add more edges than needed. (two SCCs may still be connected by a one way connection).

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-edges-to-be-added-in-a-directed-graph-so-that-any-node-can-be-reachable-from-a-given-node/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-edges-to-be-added-in-a-directed-graph-so-that-any-node-can-be-reachable-from-a-given-node/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Henry, the tricky part of the question is to understand that either finding weakly or even strongly-connected components and just adding one-route each to such components wont do.

A good example as @Henry pointed out is: `L->P exists; adding Delhi, just needs adding one route to L`

For the argument against `weakly connected components`, consider `L->P<-C; we need atleast two routes but there's only 1 weakly connected component`

My approach:

1. Sort all cities based on their number of incoming-routes (lowest first) -> Lets call this list as `in_degree_sorted_cities`
2. Pop element from this list; and:

   a. Add a new route to this city;

   b. Do a BFS and remove all the reachable cities from the `in_degree_sorted_cities` list.

---

<s>I would consider this approach:</s>

1. Find all the `connected-components` in the graph.
2. To access all the cities, you just need to add new routes (to and fro route to any one city in each connected-component) to each of these `connected-sub-graphs`.

#### Connected-component

Any two nodes in a `connected-component` can be reached from one another either by direct-route or indirect.

#### Proof by contradiction:

Since you are looking to add minimum number of connections, I think the proof is straightforward by contraction.

For example if u remove any one of those connections to a connected-component, you can no longer access it.

Comment: What do you mean by a "connected component"? For a strongly connected component one may add more routes than necessary, for a weakly connected component any two nodes in the component can not necessarily reach each other.

Comment: I defined the connected-component in the answer above

Comment: Ok, so it means a strongly connected component. But then this answer has the same problem as your previous one. Take for example 2 nodes connected by a one way route. This makes two components. But one additional route is enough to make both reachable from a new city.

Comment: Yes, its the same; just this one has some more relevant explanation.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure whats the exact concern you have?

Comment: I see, my answer was a little unclear. When i meant `add new routes` to any of the city in each connected-component; I meant: `adding a to and fro route` ; i.e. `2-routes for every connected-component`.

Comment: @Henry edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity

Comment: You still did not see my point. Lets say we have just 2 cities London and Paris and a one way route between them London->Paris. Now we add Delhi. One route Delhi->London is enough to reach both original cities from Delhi.

Comment: Oh crap, sorry I am embarrased I didnt realize that :|
I see it now. I guess this problem then needs to target building routes based on highest-outgoing-nodes and simultaneously do a BFS/DFS to remove the cities that are reachable

Comment: @Henry I've elaborated my new answer, what do u think?

Comment: I think a simpler approach could possibly work (however, I have not thought this through completely): identify the strongly connected components. From the new city add a route to one node in each SCC that does not have incoming connections from another SCC.

Comment: What about the cases like : if there's only one strongly-connected component = C; and the Graph= `CityX -> C`. You would end up adding two routes, but only one is needed

Comment: What is CityX? When it was there originally there are 2 SCCs: CityX and C. I would then just add one route from the new city to CityX because C has an incoming connection. Otherwise, if CityX is the new city it would not have any connections yet.

Comment: I see, in that case we would anyway need the precedence order. So technically you will have to order them by someway

Comment: Having a precedence order would make your approach quite similar to mine, infact maybe we dont even need to find the strongly-connected-components since a simple BFS would suffice